# How does one upgrade ubuntu (any version to latest version) using an ISO image?

Tags: upgrade, iso

If one have the slow internet connection or a limited data plan or sometime no connectivity; Then how one can upgrade ubuntu from any older version to latest version of ubuntu using only iso image of latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a bootable USB or DVD. Load it up like a fresh install then you can pick the option to "Upgrade".

[image]

Comment: Does any latest version support this type of up-gradation from any lower version. And what time it takes to upgrade the system to latest version from any version ( consider version 10.4LTs to 14.04Lts)

Comment: Which version do you have? I don't know the exact details but Canonical is still supporting 8.04 LTS. Therefore, in theory you can upgrade from 8.04 LTS -> 10.04 LTS -> 12.04 LTS -> ... -> 14.04 LTS. More information can be found here - [Ubuntu UpgradeNotes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes)